# パッケージの分類に悩んでいるクラス群があるのですが

Tags: android, model-view-controller

MVCをベースに現在後述のようにクラス分けを行っていて、
最後の`その他Fragment関連のもの`にあるクラスをどうすべきか悩んでいます。

主に`1画面1Fragment1カスタムViewGroup[1DataLoader1Data]`という感じで設計してきました。
`カスタムViewGroup`を作成したのはviewに当たるクラスを自分でnewしたくなかったというのと、
こうすることによってそのクラスにFragmentからrootViewを渡す必要がなくなるからです。
そんなFragmentは、主に`DataLoader系`や`Setting系`の生成をしているだけです。

分類に悩んでいるクラス群はそんな`カスタムViewGroup`や画面の設定等を定義したクラス群です。
`HeaderViewCreator`も`カスタムViewGroup`にしてCreatorを取るつもりでしたが、
controllerにやらせるべきだろう記述があるのでそのままになっています。
他にも`PagerView`や`PhotoListView`などにもcontrollerにやらせるべきだろう記述が
混ざっていたりします。
また、`Setting系`はカスタムViewにすべきでない？したとしても名前どうする？
という感じでそのままになっています。
また、`LoginFragment`や`DialogFragment系`については分離することに意味があるのかわからず
そのままになっています。

少なくとも厳密にMVCでなくても`その他Fragment関連のもの`にあるクラスを自分で納得できる形で
必要に応じて中身を整理するなどして1つのパッケージもしくは複数のパッケージに分類できたらと考えているのですが、どうすれば良いかがわかりません。

`View系`はcontrollerが混ざっていたとしてもview_controllerとしてまとめればいい
と考えていますが、他の`Setting系`はどうする？そもそも`SettingPhoto`はいらないのでは？
という感じです。

そもそもの設計に良くない部分があるかもしれませんが、
どうかどなたかアドバイス等よろしくお願い致します。

```
ルート
├── MainActivity ----------------------- UserEventによる画面遷移等を定義
├── base ------------------------------- ベースクラス用
│   ├── BaseDialogFragment ------------- DialogFragmentのベースクラス
│   ├── BaseFragment ------------------- Fragmentのベースクラス
│   └── BindableAdapter ---------------- Adapterのベースクラス
├── fragment --------------------------- FragmentやDialogFragment用
│   ├── HeaderFragment ----------------- ヘッダーを含む画面のベースクラス
│   ├── LoginFragment ------------------ ログイン画面
│   ├── PhotoFragment ------------------ 写真拡大画面
│   ├── PhotoListFragment -------------- 写真一覧画面
│   ├── PriceListFragment -------------- 価格表画面
│   ├── WebViewFragment ---------------- WebView画面
│   └── dialog ------------------------- DialogFragment用
│       ├── ConfirmDialogFragment ------ 確認ダイアログ
│       └── MessageDialogFragment ------ 表示ダイアログ
├── model------------------------------- モデル用
│   ├── Api ---------------------------- APIを叩くのに使用
│   ├── AppController ------------------ Application　Volleyの管理
│   ├── PagerData ---------------------- ページャ表示に必要なデータを保持
│   ├── PagerDataLoader ---------------- ページャ表示に必要なデータをロード
│   ├── PhotoDownloader ----- ---------- 写真をSDにダウンロード
│   ├── PhotoItem ---------------------- 写真一覧の1アイテムのデータを保持
│   ├── PhotoListData ------------------ 写真一覧表示に必要なデータを保持
│   ├── PhotoListDataLoader ------------ 写真一覧表示に必要なデータをロード
│   ├── PriceItem ---------------------- 価格表の1アイテムのデータを保持
│   ├── PriceListData ------------------ 価格表表示に必要なデータを保持
│   ├── PriceListDataLoader ------------ 価格表表示に必要なデータをロード
│   ├── User --------------------------- ログイン・ログアウト処理を定義　状態を保持
│   ├── UserEvent ---------------------- ユーザーイベント(○○画面へ行くなど)
│   └── Watermark ---------------------- PhotoView系のBitmapに透かしをつける
├── utility ---------------------------- ユーティリティー用
│   ├── Animation ---------------------- 画面遷移時に使うアニメーションを定義
│   └── UrlUtility --------------------- URLに関するユーティリティーメソッドを定義
├── view ------------------------------- カスタムViewやAdapter用
│   ├── CategoryView ------------------- カテゴリ名用のカスタムTextView
│   ├── PhotoView ---------------------- 写真用のカスタムImageView
│   ├── ScalingPhotoView --------------- 写真拡大用のカスタムPhotoView
│   └── adapter ------------------------ Adapter用
│       ├── PhotoListAdapter ----------- 写真一覧用カスタムBindableAdapter
│       └── PriceListAdapter ----------- 価格表用カスタムBindableAdapter
└── その他Fragment関連のもの ------------------------ 以下を一括りにするか、もしくは－
    ├── HeaderViewCreator -------------- ヘッダーの設定と挙動の定義
    ├── PagerView ---------------------- 写真一覧のページャ用カスタムFrameLayout
    ├── PhotoItemView ------------------ 写真一覧の1アイテム用カスタLinearLayout
    ├── PhotoListView ------------------ PhotoListFragmentのカスタムLinerLayout
    ├── PriceListView ------------------ PriceListFragmentのカスタムLinerLayout
    ├── SettingPhoto ------------------- ScalingPhotoViewにロードを頼むだけ
    └── SettingWebView ----------------- WebViewの設定とURLによる挙動を定義
```

Answer (score 1):

MVCに関しては様々なご意見がありますのでご参考まで。

今のところ私は以下のように分類しています。

- Controller

  - 処理のエントリーポイント (onCreate, onClick など)
  - UI操作などのイベントを受けて Model に処理を指示する
  - Activity, Fragment などが主に該当する
  - 設計次第では BroadcastReceiver や Service が該当する場合もある
- View

  - View を継承したクラス (カスタム View)
- ModelViewAdapter

  - ArrayAdapter など、 Model と View の橋渡し役
- Model

  - Controller にも View にも属さないものすべて
  - Model が更新されたら View などに通知して更新する